# Trying to delay images placed on UIButtons

Tags: ios, xcode, timer, swift2

I am trying to deal a hand of 5 cards, one at a time, with a slight delay between the deal of each card. The card's are UIButtons and I am changing the button image to that of a card.  My code is below.  I've tried solutions with NSTimer also but get the same results.  The problem is that no matter what the delay time interval is, the delay occurs but then all the cards appear at once.  Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    var index = 0
    for card in [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5] {
        if canBeDealt(card)  {
            let oneCard = myDeck.deal1()
            pokerHand[index] = oneCard
            let cardPic = UIImage(named: "PNGCards/" + oneCard + ".png")!
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                card.setBackgroundImage(cardPic, forState: .Normal)
                card.setTitle("", forState: .Normal)
            }
        }
        index += 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `dispatch_after` is an async function so it returns immediately. You starts a new iteration of the loop milliseconds later, so all cards appears to show up at once. You need to introduce a `delay` variable:

```
var delay = 0.0

for card in [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5] {
    if canBeDealt(card) {
        // ...

        delay += 0.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            card.setBackgroundImage(cardPic, forState: .Normal)
            card.setTitle("", forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That did it answer my question.  Unfortunately I have other problems and I think I'm going to have to use multiple threads.  Thanks again, your answer was spot on.  Gil